# Make XAML Controls "go on top" of other controls when mouse over

Tags: xaml

I have three buttons, one on top of the other in XAML like so:

```
<Grid>
    <Button
        Width="50"
        Height="50"
        Background="Red"/>
    <Button
        Margin="10"
        Width="50"
        Height="50"
        Background="Blue"/>
    <Button
        Margin="20"
        Width="50"
        Height="50"
        Background="Green"/>
</Grid>
```

How do I change their Z-Order when the mouse is over them?

Answer (score 1):

Put this to the `Grid.Resources`

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="99999"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

when `IsMouseOver` is false the button instances gets back its original zindex value